# Count the number of user sessions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with ip's and a view date and for websites with a website id

```
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| website_id | ip        | view_date           |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 123        | 123123123 | 2014-01-01 10:23:00 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 123        | 987987987 | 2014-01-01 10:23:00 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 123        | 123123123 | 2014-01-01 10:26:00 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 123        | 987987987 | 2014-01-01 10:24:00 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 123        | 987987987 | 2014-01-01 10:25:00 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 123        | 123123123 | 2014-01-02 03:23:00 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

I would like to get sessions from the table, which would be a time someone starts on the site until they are done. To find out when they were done there is 30 minutes or more of no activity after one of the between 2 view dates when view_date is ordered desc.

So, with this example data I have 2 users `123123123` and `987987987`

- User `123123123` has 2 sessions because row 3 happened with in 30 minutes of row 1 and row 6 happened more than 30 minutes after row 3
- User `987987987` has 1 session because row 4 happened less than 30 minutes after row 2 and row 5 happened less than 30 minutes after row 4

I have no idea how I would calculate that using MySQL. I all I know is to take the data order it by `ip`, then by `view_date`. After that I am lost.

When I say session I mean:

> a period of time devoted to a particular activity.

And Not:

> a way of tracking people between multiple web pages.

Desired Output:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| website_id | ip        | sessions |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| 123        | 123123123 | 2        |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| 123        | 987987987 | 1        |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: This table structure is working already? Are you collection data right now?

Comment: Yes, I have millions of rows

Comment: So what is the desired output? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @JChao Okay I have updated the question please look

Comment: your issue with this is you have no identifier of what is the start of a session... as in there needs to be another column that identifies which date is the start of a new session...

Comment: What I was thinking could be done (if possible) is to just look at the previous record and the current record 30 or less = same session; 30+ new session. I otherwise don't have that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ip, sum(session) + 1 as session
from (
    select
    t.*,
    if(@previp = ip and timestampdiff(minute, @prevview, view_date) >= 30, 1, 0) as session,
    @previp := ip,
    @prevview := view_date
    from
    Table1 t
    , (select @prevview := (select view_date from Table1 order by ip, view_date limit 1), 
       @previp := null) var_init_subquery
    order by ip, view_date
) sq
group by ip
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccb33/4/0)
- read more about user defined [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution

I do a count to find out the number of rows for a given website id and ip address that occur between the date and the date -30 minutes. If its 0 assign a 1 meaning its a new session else give it a 0. Then do a sum.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51b21/3)**

```
select website_id,
    ip,
    sum(newSession) as Sessions
from
(select *,
case 
    when (select count(*) 
          from yourTable ytb 
          where ytb.website_id = yta.website_id 
          and ytb.ip = yta.ip 
          and ytb.view_date < yta.view_date 
          and ytb.view_date > date_add(yta.view_date, INTERVAL -30 MINUTE)) = 0 then 1
    else 0
end as newSession
from yourtable yta) baseTable
GROUP BY website_id, ip
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @a := null;
SET @b := null;
SET @c := null;
SELECT website_id, ip, view_date, COUNT(counting) as num_sessions
FROM
(   SELECT website_id, ip, view_date, 
        @c := if(@a = ip AND @b BETWEEN view_date - interval 30 minute AND view_date, @c + 1, 1) as counting, 
        @a := ip, @b := view_date
    FROM
    (   SELECT * 
        FROM sessions
        ORDER BY ip, view_date
    )t
)t1
WHERE counting = 1
GROUP BY ip;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c628f/1)

Answer (score -1):

After sorting according to time and IP you can use cursors to find the total number of sessions. You can get more information on mysql cursors from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html).

More details :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE i INT;
  DECLARE prev_i INT;
  DECLARE d DATE;
  DECLARE prev_d DATE;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ip, view_date FROM table;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    IF prev_i == NULL THEN
        FETCH cur1 INTO prev_i, prev_d;
    END IF;
    FETCH cur1 INTO i, d;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF prev_i == i && INTERVAL_BETWEEN(prev_d, d) > 30min THEN
      ADD_IN_SESSIONS_FOR_i ;
    END IF;
    prev_i = i;
    prev_d = d;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

Comment: That doesnt provide an answer for the question. Please add more info.

Comment: it is a link only answer too